# How to make i18n support filenames in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, internationalization

So i have a standard file located at:

```
/sites/default/files/hello.png
```

I can access it like so:

```
http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/hello.png
```

However, with i18n, it would be nice if the prefixed paths would also work for these files. For example, this link doesn't work:

```
http://www.example.com/us/sites/default/files/hello.png
```

But it doesn't.

So my question is, how can I make these "country-specific" paths also work for files?

I am thinking I might need to do something in htaccess and then also create a module that filters and redirects these paths, but that just sounds like way too much effort and that perhaps I am missing the easy way to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use htaccess to make all language-version URLs redirect to the default URL for files/images.
If you do this you won't need to do anything further in your drupal code (e.g. a custom module).

Your rewrite rule would look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]*)/sites/default/files/(.*)$ sites/default/files/$2 [R=301,L]
```

**Updated**

If your site is in a subdirectory e.g. 'drupal', you could modify your rewrite rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^drupal/([a-zA-Z-]*)/sites/default/files/(.*)$ drupal/sites/default/files/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That will give 404 if drupal $base_path is not "/". You need a way to keep the base_path and not setting it exclusively to "/".

Comment: I want to mark this as yes, but would love some insight into how to get around the / issue?

Comment: I have removed the first `/` in the first example as it isn't needed but I believe the best way to deal with drupal installations in sub-directories (i.e. $base_path is not '/') is the example I added under "Updated".